# Use Perl to Read input .csv file, bring to array and extract to expected output

Tags: arrays, perl, csv

I got a request to make perl script using array uniq,

my @filtered = uniq(@array);

But don't know how to code it by perl

Any one can help me, it's appreciate..

======================================================

1) Input .csv file:

```
ATPG         TCD             tcd/T1, xxx/tcd/T2        
ATPG         INSTANCE        inst1/I1, xxx/inst2/I2, inst3/I3   
ATPG         PATTERN         pat1/P1, pat2/P2   
SIM          BLACKBOX        bb1/B1, bb2/B2
```

2) Request:

STEP 1: read input .csv file

STEP 2: create output out.txt with expected contents

======================================================

3) output out.txt (if (1st column = ATPG))

```
// TCD

read_core_description     tcd/T1
read_core_description     xxx/tcd/T2

// INSTANCE
add_core_instance  -instance inst1/I1  
add_core_instance  -instance xxx/inst2/I2   
add_core_instance  -instance inst3/I3

//PATTERN 
read_patterns pat1/P1  
read_patterns pat2/P2
```

======================================================

My current code here, pls help to continue at the end

```
#1) Open input
my $inF="input.csv";
open( my $inF_var, "<", $inF) || die ("Can't open input file\n");

#2) Open output
my $outF_Blk="output/out.txt";

open( my $outF_Blk_var,  ">$outF_Blk") || die ("Can't open output file");


#3) Write to files
while( <$inF_var> ){
next if (/^$/);
my $line=$_;

my @value=split(/:/, $line);

# EXTRACT THE EXPECTED OUTPUT HERE # 
### NEED EVERYONE CAN HELP ####
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code yet, then Stack Overflow is not the best place for your question.

Comment: @DaveCross: yes, I can read .csv file by using perl, 
but don't know how to adapt above requirement, 
That's the reason why I need a hand here,
could you pls give suggestion something. Thanks

Comment: That really doesn't answer my questions. Show us your code.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, one option would be to use 3 arrays for TCD / INSTANCE / PATTERN one each, and populate them as you read the input, then print the output as needed.

Comment: @DaveCross: , I've updated my code to above topic

Comment: @CashLo: can you show your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only implemented one of the types of output. The others should be simple enough to add.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my %process = (
  TCD      => \&process_tcd,
  INSTANCE => \&process_instance,
  PATTERN  => \&process_pattern,
);

while (<DATA>) {
  my ($type, $cmd, @row) = split /[\s,]+/;

  next unless $type eq 'ATPG';

  if (!exists $process{$cmd}) {
    warn "Unknown record type: $_";
    next;
  }

  $process{$cmd}->(@row);
}

sub process_tcd {
  my @data = @_;

  say "//TCD\n";
  say "read_core_description    $_" for @data;
  say '';
}

sub process_instance {}
sub process_pattern {}

__DATA__
ATPG         TCD             tcd/T1, xxx/tcd/T2        
ATPG         INSTANCE        inst1/I1, xxx/inst2/I2, inst3/I3   
ATPG         PATTERN         pat1/P1, pat2/P2   
SIM          BLACKBOX        bb1/B1, bb2/B2
```

Comment: it's great. Thanks a lot. 
just 1 note, feature 'say' not available in my perl.So, I change 'say' to 'print'

Comment: @KhanhNguyen: `say()` was added to Perl 5.10 in 2007. You should really be using a version that supports it.